# How does Amazon EC2 operating system licensing work?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm new to the cloud and EC2 and am wondering how licensing of operating systems works. Specifically, i spent some time looking at amazon machine images (ami's) and some contain windows and sql server. My question is how does the licensing work:

a) Do I install my own licenses once the boxes are available?
b) Are these licenses covered by my Amazon bill
c) what are any costs associated with this software?

Thank in advance,

JP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your license fees are included in the hourly run-time charge from Amazon. It's a data center license, so you do not need to (nor are you ALLOWED to) install any license you may already own. As for terminal server/remote desktop service CALs, these can be purchased or installed. The server can be made part of your existing AD domain and contact your existing licensing server, or you can run it in workgroup mode and activate licensing service on the AWS EC2 server itself.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Can_I_use_my_existing_Windows_Server_license_with_EC2

Answer (score -1):

The answer I got from Microsoft was:  The EC2 server license includes two licenses for an Admin.  That way you can login and configure the box.  If you setup remote desktop (RDS), you'll have to purchase Windows CALs and RDS CALs.